# **/<pattern> ignoring all files of <pattern> except in two directories

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a .gitignore file with just the pattern `**/*.pyc` and it ignores all .pyc files except in two directories.  There are other directories it works for that have longer and shorter names.  When I change the name of one to something like "Axiom_Blob" instead, it works.  What is it about these names that eludes git?  I'm using version 1.9.5.

```
 modified:   Axiom_AIR_25_49_61/Axiom_AIR_25_49_61.pyc
 modified:   Axiom_AIR_25_49_61/__init__.pyc
 modified:   Axiom_AIR_Mini32/AxiomAirMini32.pyc
 modified:   Axiom_AIR_Mini32/__init__.pyc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is clear from your example. All of the files that you list are preceded by the word `modified:`. This means that these files were already committed to Git, and therefore, `.gitignore` has no affect. `.gitignore` is only for untracked files.

If you cannot delete them, use

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <your-files>
```

A better solution, assuming they should have never been committed in the first place, is to purge these files from the history. This can be easily accomplished with [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)